# Generate a Word document using different languages

Tags: apache-poi

I want to create a Word document that uses different languages. In particular, I have a two-language original text where the language changes between English and German for each paragraph. This is what I tried:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFStyles;

public class DocxCreator {

  public static void createDocument(File docxOutput) throws IOException {

    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
    XWPFStyles docStyles = doc.createStyles();
    docStyles.setSpellingLanguage("de-DE");

    {
      XWPFParagraph para = doc.createParagraph();
      XWPFRun run = para.createRun();
      run.setLanguage("de-DE"); // XXX: this method does not exist
      para.setText("Deutsch");
    }

    {
      XWPFParagraph para = doc.createParagraph();
      XWPFRun paraRun = para.createRun();
      para.setStyle("en-US");
      paraRun.setText("English");
    }

    /*- XXX: How do I add the style “en-US” to the document and set its language to en-US”? */

    /* XXX: How do I enable global grammar and spell checking? */

    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(docxOutput)) {
      doc.write(fos);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    createDocument(new File("multilang.docx"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not just write the text in and be done with it? Why do you need to tell Word what language it is in?

Comment: Because I have a bilangual source text that I want to convert into a Word document, in order to use Word’s spellchecking. And I don’t want to manually mark each second paragraph as German or English, since that’s a task a computer can do easily for me.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think this is currently supported by POI.

Generally, the language of the text is specified on the XWPFRun (XWPF) / CharacterRun (HWPF) level.

- For HWPF (old binary *.doc format) there exists at least a method [`CharacterRun.getLanguageCode()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/usermodel/CharacterRun.html#getLanguageCode%28%29) - but no respective setter.
- For XWPF (new *.docx format) I do not see such a thing at all.

The language codes are the same for *.doc and *.docx. A list is available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd953371%28v=office.12%29.aspx).